# View local PDF in R shiny Dashboard in Chrome Browser

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to open a pdf file which is stored in my computer (D Drive) only. I have tried various links like 
 https://gist.github.com/aagarw30/d5aa49864674aaf74951 &

[displaying a pdf from a local drive in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469978/displaying-a-pdf-from-a-local-drive-in-shiny])

I can display a pdf file if it is on the web but can't do it if it is on my local drive.

Can anyone please provide with a sample answer

Answer (score 0):

If you can put the pdf file under the `www` subfolder of your project, then you can just use the following code

```
  tags$iframe(style="height:400px; width:100%; scrolling:yes", src="test.pdf")
```

Having web browser opening local files is a security risk, and most modern browsers do not allows this. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don't_work