# How to display dynamically generated PDF files inside shiny golem app

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, golem

I'm generating a powerpoint presentation in R using `officer`, and then converting this to a PDF so a user can preview slides inside the shiny golem app. But after referencing [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-www-folder-save-and-display-pdf/6574/7) and [this SO answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39585058/9489566) I'm still not quite sure how to accomplish this. I am able to display external PDFs located in inst/app/www inside an iframe, but not sure how to do this for PDFs generated inside the app itself.

Here is the relevant code snippet from my app_server.R file:

```
  output$preview <- renderUI({

  # Creates rpptx object with one slide
  preview_rpptx <- add_title_slide(x = NULL, title = input_list[["title"]]) 

  # Creates www/ directory if it doesn't exist
  if (!dir_exists("www")) dir_create("www")

  # Generates .pptx file 
  pptx_file_path <- file_temp("preview", tmp_dir = "www", ext = ".pptx")
  print(preview_rpptx, pptx_file_path)
  
  # Converts .pptx to .pdf 
  pdf_file_path <- file_temp("preview", tmp_dir = "www", ext = ".pdf")
  convert_to_pdf(path = pptx_file_path, pdf_file = pdf_file_path)
  
  tags$iframe(style = "height:600px; width:100%", src = str_sub(pdf_file_path, 5))
}
```

Running the app, I get a "Not Found" error inside the iframe. But I can see that the PDF file was generated properly in the www/ directory.

Comment: If you want to embed a pdf in a prettier way than the iframe way, I can show you how to do with the [pdfobject](https://pdfobject.com/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know how to do with a file as you ask, I would encode this file to a **base64** string and set this string to the `src` attribute:

```
library(base64enc)

output$preview <- renderUI({

  ......
    
  pdf_file_path <- "PATH/TO/PDF_FILE"
  b64 <- dataURI(file = pdf_file_path, mime = "application/pdf")
  
  tags$iframe(
    style = "height: 600px; width: 100%;", src = b64
  )
  
}
```

Comment: This works well! Thank you! I am curious what the approach would look like using the `pdfobject` library.