# Why does my Shiny iframe tell me "localhost didn’t send any data" when trying to display a local PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, iframe, shiny

### Intention:

I'm trying to build a Shiny app that contains a pdf viewer. I'm trying my best to replicate this example:

[displaying a pdf from a local drive in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469978/displaying-a-pdf-from-a-local-drive-in-shiny/21024943#21024943)

### Problem:

In the reprex below, I download a dummy pdf into the 'www' directory in the same root as 'App.R'.

As far as I can understand, the http protocols innate to Shiny apps require me to set the source for the iframe as `"http://localhost/test.pdf"`, as opposed to `"www/test.pdf"`. But when I run this code, I get an iframe with nothing but this in:

[image: "Aw Snap!" emote, with message: localhost didn't send any data]

I've also followed the additional advice in the previously mentioned SO thread - running the app using the 'Run App' button in RStudio, instead of Ctrl+return-ing through the code. No success. Anyone know how I can make this work?

### Reprex:

```r
require(shiny)
#> Loading required package: shiny

ui = fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("pdfViewer")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  ### Libraries
  require(pdftools)
  
  ### Create 'www' dir (understand that this
  ### is where 'localhost' stuff is kept?)
  suppressWarnings(dir.create("www"))
  
  ### Make a test pdf file using the w3 dummy pdf
  pdf = "www/test.pdf"
  download.file(url = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
                       destfile = pdf)
  
  ### Define the http: address for the pdf
  pdfHttp = "http://localhost/test.pdf"
  
  output$pdfViewer = 
    renderText({
      ### Copied this from here: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024943/11149547"
      return(paste('<iframe style="height:600px; width:100%" src="', pdfHttp, '"></iframe>', sep = ""))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Appendix (R version data)

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

Comment: have you tried using a relative path for the pdf file. Like `test.pdf` or `www/test.pdf`?

Comment: From what I've read (see the link above), the iframe requires a reference to `localhost`, rather than a relative path. If you can get a relative path to work I'd be very interested in hearing about it.

Comment: You save it to a `www` folder, but then your pdfHttp path doesn't include that `www` folder. Why?

Comment: Because `pdfHttp` isn't a path to a local file, but a web address within a local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I needed to add a port to the local host address.

I've learnt that `http://localhost` is synonymous with `http://127.0.0.1`. I then noticed that when my Shiny App was running in browser, the omnibox listed the address as: `127.0.0.1:5056`.

I replaced `http://localhost/test.pdf` in the above code with `http://127.0.0.1:6056/test.pdf`, and now the pdf loads.

I imagine this is related to the fact that I'm using my work computer, which part of a local network of some kind.

### Edit:

Furthermore, you can explicitly define the port my running `options(shiny.port = 6056)` before you run `runApp(server = server, ui = ui)`. I needed to do this in the end, because my other Shiny App (not reprex) launched to a different port.