# Where is the local host directory of a shiny app in R to display local pdf file?

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I am Looking at this Question: [displaying a pdf from a local drive in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469978/displaying-a-pdf-from-a-local-drive-in-shiny) and want to Display a local pdf file.

I placed my pdf within `C:\Users\user1\Documents\shiny_pdf\www`. The app is placed in `C:\Users\user1\Documents\shiny_pdf` and i set my working Directory to the latter Directory.

Now i am unsure on how to reference that file within the app.

The author of the answer post in the linked Question states:

> so you have to save them in your www directory (a local web server)
>   and access to files with their http(s): URLs (the URL will be
>   something like http://localhost/.../mypdf.pdf)

So i am unsure on how to navigate from `http://localhost/` to `C:\Users\user1\Documents\shiny_pdf\www`.

**What i tried:**

- I would have assumed i have `www` is the Server Directory so i would use `http://localhost/R-intro.pdf`.
- I added an Image to my shiny app and checked its server address in the browser. Then i located the pdf file accordingly. I can open it via: `http://127.0.0.1:6023/r-intro.pdf` (with 6023 being my port number). But i cant use that either to reference it in the iframe.
- I also tried `list.files()`, but that would (obv.) give me the files from the working Directory.
- `http://localhost/R-intro.pdf` also does not work.

**The error:**

> Fehler: Verbindung fehlgeschlagen
>   Firefox kann keine Verbindung zu dem Server unter localhost aufbauen.

which loosely translates to. Connection failed. Firefox can´t make a Connection to the Server under localhost.

**Reproducible Code:**

1. Save the following file (see below) as, e.g. `app.R`.
2. Run the following Code to create a WWW directoy for shiny and place a sample pdf into it.

`dir.create("www")
pdf(file = "www/r-intro.pdf")
plot(1)
dev.off()
list.files()`

Here the Code to save in e.g. `app.R`.

**Code:**

```
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    print(list.files("http://localhost/R-intro.pdf"))
  })

  output$pdfviewer <- renderText({
    return(paste('<iframe style="height:600px; width:100%" src="', input$pdfurl, '"></iframe>', sep = ""))
  })

})


row <- function(...) {
  tags$div(class="row", ...)
}

col <- function(width, ...) {
  tags$div(class=paste0("span", width), ...)
}

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

  headerPanel("PDF VIEWER"),

  mainPanel(

    tags$div(
      class = "container",

      row(
        col(3, textInput("pdfurl", "PDF URL"))
      ),
      row(
        col(6, htmlOutput('pdfviewer')),
        col(6, tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="https://localhost/www/R-intro.pdf"))
      )
    )
  )
))


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ok, against advice from the post

`col(6, tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="R-intro.pdf"))`,

just referencing the file seems to work.