# R Shiny: How to fetch pdf file from remote server and display it in an iframe

Tags: r, pdf, iframe, shiny, remote-server

I am looking to build a Shiny app where users can select a pdf file (with some extra info), which is then displayed in-app.

I was able to pull up a pdf from files placed in the app's `www/` directory, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469978/displaying-a-pdf-from-a-local-drive-in-shiny).

Below is my demo app. To run this, make a directory `www/reports/` next to your `app.R` and place 3 pdfs in there named `report1.pdf`, `report2.pdf` and `report3.pdf`. Or download my project folder [here](https://file.io/LRYKpp27Ka3G). Run the app in the browser to see the full pdf viewer.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select_pdf", "Select PDF file", choices = c("report1.pdf", "report2.pdf", "report3.pdf")),
  actionButton("btn_view_pdf", "View PDF"),
  htmlOutput("pdfviewer")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Construct pdf filepath on button click
  pdf_filepath <- eventReactive(input$btn_view_pdf, {
    pdf_dir <- "reports"
    file.path(pdf_dir, input$select_pdf)
  })

  # Show PDF in iframe
  output$pdfviewer <- renderText({
    paste('<iframe style="height:1000px; width:50%" src="', pdf_filepath(), '"></iframe>', sep = "")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

While this works nicely, it is not enough for my purpose. The pdfs I want to show currently live on our company HPC server, and there are thousands of pdfs, i.e. I can't copy all of them into the `www/` directory inside my shiny app.

Is there a way to **1) directly fetch the pdfs from the company server** and **2) feed them into the iframe**? I have credentials to access the company server file tree (via ssh) and could probably put them into environment variables on the server that hosts the shiny app.

Can you point me to any best practices, resources or packages for this? I thought this is a common thing to do, but I am not finding much info out there. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the names and locations of the remote PDF files before downloading them, or do you need to `ls` them to know what's available?

Comment: Hi. I will know the exact filepaths and filenames for each PDF on the company server.